# How to create these plots?

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks

I don´t know how to make this plots like in picture below. I need it for my final thesis. Thanks for any help.

[image: Picture which I need]

Once again, thanks for any help.

Comment: @ kileuskas Welcome on TeX.SE. Questions like "do this graph for me" are not great since the principle here is to show what you have already achieved in a 'Minimal Working Example" (MWE) people can start working on. I'm in the field so I understood you wanted the pay-off diagram of an option at maturity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,export]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
    CallMatu(\x,\KK,\Prime) = max(0,\x-\KK) - \Prime ;
    PutMatu(\x,\KK,\Prime) = max(0,\KK-\x) - \Prime ;
        }
}

\pgfplotsset{
    BSMatu/.style= {red,line width=1.8pt},
}

\begin{document}

\def\KK{100}
\def\Prime{5}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
                xlabel= Underlying price $S_{t}$,
                ylabel={PnL at maturity},
                domain=0:200,
                samples=101,
                axis on top,
                axis line style={black!40},
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},anchor=north, draw=none}
            ]                           
            \addplot[BSMatu] (x,{CallMatu(x,\KK,\Prime)});
            \addlegendentry{Call pay-off at maturity}
%           \addplot[BSMatu] (x,{PutMatu(x,\KK,\Prime)});
%           \addlegendentry{Put pay-off at maturity}
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple with `pstricks`. Here is an example with the first plot:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}%
\usepackage{sansmath} 
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}\sansmath
    \psset{unit=2cm, linejoin=1, showorigin, ticksize=-3pt 0.4pt}
    \psaxes[Ox=50, Dx=50, dx=1, Dy=5, dy=0.4](0,0)(2,0)(0,4)
    \uput{8pt}[d](0,0){$ 50 $}
    \psline[linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed](0,0)(1,0)(2,4)
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pgfplots and tikzpicture packages, and then set up all of the individual conditions of the graphs (e.g. the axes, the axes labels, and the numbers on the axes and their frequencies).

Although you *could* plot the individual points, these graphs seem to be linear, so you can just find the equation for the line (using a little point-slope form) and then plot them on the graph.

More information here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf